# WMI query - CPU LoadPercentage

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I´m searching for a better way to get the CPU load in percent with WMI from multiple systems(means different CPUs etc.).
My code is working, but I think there is a better way to get over all CPU usage in percent.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

```
SelectQuery queryCpuUsage = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectSearcher cpuUsage = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, queryCpuUsage);                                       
ManagementObjectCollection cpuUsageCollection = cpuUsage.Get();                                                       

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in cpuUsageCollection)
{                                           
iCPU++;
calcCPU = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["LoadPercentage"]);
perCPU = perCPU + calcCPU;
}

perCPU = perCPU / iCPU;

cpuUsageCollection.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine("LoadPercentage CPU: {0}", perCPU);
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally I'd go for the [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class because it is much more precise. You will need to query both **PercentProcessorTime** and **TimeStamp_Sys100NS**. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757283%28WS.10%29.aspx) you can find the exact formula.